# Blazor Dynamic Component @bind

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to create a Dynamic component and in parameters I am trying to pass "@bind-Value" but its giving me exception saying bind-Value doesn't exist.
My question is while creating a Dynamic component how we can specify bi-directional binding.

```
<DynamicComponent Type="context.Item.RenderComponent" Parameters="context.Item.RenderComponentParameters" />
```

and my parameter objects looks like this

```
     RenderComponentParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
 {
     { "@bind-Value", property },         
 },
```

Comment: Is your component have an Input?

Comment: Yes, its a text box and I am passing parameters as "@bind-Text" with corresponding property for directional binding but dynamic component doesn't considers "bind-Text" as a valid parameter

Comment: 1. can you show C# code of the dynamically rendered component? 2. Do you want two-way binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@bind-Value` directive is syntax shortcut for Value=".." and ValueChanged="..." and optionally ValueExpression="...", so you might want to add those parameters.

1. Make sure your Component supports two way databinding by defining both, Value parameter and ValueChanged event callback parameter and optionally ValueExpression.
2. Define the parameters' values in your `RenderComponentParameters`

   ```
   Expression<Func<string>> valueExpression = () => ...

   dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
   {
     { "Value", property },         
     { "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, val => ...)},
     { "ValueExpression", valueExpression } //optional
   },
   ```

---

I recommend you to inspect C# code generated from .razor code (Razor syntax translated to C#). For example you might inspect how @bind-Value is translated, so that you can emulate it here.

Add this to your .csproj: `<EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>`, see this [article](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-source-generator-part-6-saving-source-generator-output-in-source-control/)

Comment: You'll probably want to add  `ValueExpression` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters is for settings ChildComponent's variables with `[Parameter]` attribute. Try following:

MyComponent.razor

```
<input @bind-value="myvalue"></input>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string myvalue { get; set; }
}
```

Home.razor

```
@page "/"
<DynamicComponent Type="mytype" Parameters="myparameters"></DynamicComponent>

@code{
    Type mytype = typeof(MyComponent);
    Dictionary<string, object> myparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "myvalue", "test bind to input" } };
}
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: this is one way binding, the OP asked for bi-directional binding